# How do I implement options in jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm using a jQuery plugin for modals to work on my website, the plugin/code has the option to change the background color of the modal, if you go at the bottom of the [plugin's website](http://joaopereirawd.github.io/animatedModal.js/) you'll see the options.

I'm sure this is probably something very simple, I'm just not sure how to implement it in the plugin's initialization code which looks like this:

```
<script>
  $("#demo01").animatedModal();
</script>
```

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't know that library, but usually you pass in an object to the function. So,

```
$("#demo01").animatedModel( {optionName: optionValue} );
```

You could always define the object before-hand as well.

```
var options = { optionName: optionValue };

$("#demo01").animatedModel(options);
```

Answer (score 0):

Options are basically passed in the function as a object. I hope it will work.

```
$("#demo01").animatedModal({
    animatedIn:'zoomIn',
    animatedOut:'bounceOut',
    color:'#39BEB9',
    beforeOpen: function() {

        // do something before open
    },
    afterClose: function() {
      //do something after close

    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 $("#demo01").animatedModal({ 
    color: 'color' 
});
```

*And if you want to add more options:*

```
 $("#demo01").animatedModal({ 
    option: value,
    option: value,
    option: value
});
```